# Доступ к вложенным элементам хэша

Tags: ruby-on-rails, хеширование

Есть yml файл с вложенными элементами, нужно загрузить всю информацию в виде хэша (используя HashWithIndifferentAccess). Пробежаться по полученному хэшу и добавить в базу данных объекты Project и Todo (todo добавить соответствующим проектам). Вот файл seeds.yml:

```
 projects:
     - title: 'Семья'
       todos:
        - text: 'Купить молоко'
          isCompleted: false
        - text: 'Заменить масло в двигателе до 23 апреля'
          isCompleted: false
        - text: 'Отправить письмо бабушке'
          isCompleted: true
        - text: 'Заплатить за квартиру'
          isCompleted: false
        - text: 'Забрать обувь из ремонта'
          isCompleted: false
     - title: 'Работа'
       todos:
        - text: 'Позвонить заказчику'
          isCompleted: true
        - text: 'Отправить документы'
          isCompleted: true
        - text: 'Заполнить отчет'
          isCompleted: false
```

Использую такую структуру (она выводит просто все элементы ассоциаций):

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.yml')
config = YAML.load_file(seed_file)
conf = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(config)
conf.each do |project|
    puts project
    puts "\n"
  end
```

Вот что выводит:

```
projects
{"title"=>"Семья", "todos"=>[{"text"=>"Купить молоко", "isCompleted"=>false}, {"text"=>"Заменить масло в двигателе до 23 апреля", "isCompleted"=>false}, {"text"=>"Отправить письмо бабушке", "isCompleted"=>true}, {"text"=>"Заплатить за квартиру", "isCompleted"=>false}, {"text"=>"Забрать обувь из ремонта", "isCompleted"=>false}]}
{"title"=>"Работа", "todos"=>[{"text"=>"Позвонить заказчику", "isCompleted"=>true}, {"text"=>"Отправить документы", "isCompleted"=>true}, {"text"=>"Заполнить отчет", "isCompleted"=>false}]}
```

Никак не могу обратиться даже к элементам "title". 
Проекты и задачи добавляются в базу так:

```
project = Project.create title: "Проект 1"
todo = Todo.create text: "Сделать что-то" 
project.todos << todo
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Выкладываю решение, вдруг кому-то поможет. Изменил структуру seeds.yml вот так

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.yml')
config = YAML.load_file(seed_file)
conf = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(config)
    conf[:projects].each do |project|
        @project = Project.create({title: project[:title]})
        puts project[:title]
        project[:todos].each do |todo|
            @project.todos.create ({text: todo[:text], isCompleted: todo[:isCompleted]})
            puts todo[:text]
        end
        @todos = @project.todos.all
        puts "\n"
      end
```

Все отлично добавляется в базу данных.